# Problema ao carregar arquivo na memória

Tags: c, c++, array, arquivo, char

Estou tentando carregar vários arquivos na memória (arquivo pequenos), mas o problema é que quando tento carregar outro arquivo logo em seguida, todos os arquivos ficam com o mesmo nome do ultimo arquivo carregado.

Eu estou utilizando uma `struct` que contém nome, tamanho do nome, dados e o tamanho dos dados, para representar os arquivos.

```
// Cabeçalho
struct AssetHeader
{
    char* version;
    long version_sz;
    int files_num;
};

// Estrutura para representar os arquivos
struct AssetData
{
    char* name;
    char* data;
    long name_sz;
    long data_sz;
};

class AssetManager
{
    protected:
        FILE* m_pFile;
        AssetHeader* m_pHeader;

        std::vector<AssetData*> m_pAssets;
        unsigned int m_FileNum;

    .....
    .....

    public:
        inline std::vector<AssetData*> getFileList() {return m_pAssets;}
        inline int getFileCount() {return (int)m_FileNum;}

        AssetData* getFileByName(std::string name);

        void createAsset(const char* name="DefaultAssetName.asset");
        void loadAsset(const char* filename);

        void addFile(const char* filename);
        void saveFile(AssetData* asset, const char* filename);

        void clear();
        void writeAsset();
        void closeAsset();

    protected:
        void writeAssetHeader();
        void writeAssetBlock(AssetData* asset);

        void readAssetHeader();
        void readAssetBlock();
};


// Carrega um arquivo na memória
void AssetManager::addFile(const char* filename)
{
    AssetData* asset = new AssetData();

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    asset->data_sz = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    asset->data = new char[asset->data_sz];

    if(fread(&asset->data[0], sizeof(char), asset->data_sz, file) == 0) {
        delete asset;
        asset = NULL;

        fclose(file);
    }

    fclose(file);

    asset->name_sz = strlen(filename);
    asset->name = (char*)filename;

    m_FileNum += 1;
    m_pAssets.push_back(asset);
    m_pHeader->files_num = m_FileNum;
}

// Utilização
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AssetManager* asset_mgr = new AssetManager();
    asset_mgr->createAsset("asset.txt");

    std::string name;

    name = "1.txt";
    asset_mgr->addFile(name.c_str());

    name = "2.txt";
    asset_mgr->addFile(name.c_str());

    asset_mgr->writeAsset();
    asset_mgr->closeAsset();

    return 0;
}
```

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado. Eu fiz um teste utilizando um `print` em cada `HAssetData` armazenado mas o problema é como eu avia dito, os arquivo ficam com o nome do ultimo arquivo carregado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você está guardando o *ponteiro* recebido diretamente na sua estrutura, o que significa guardar o ponteiro para a string contida na variável `name`. Por isso, quando o conteúdo apontado muda para "2.txt", é esse conteúdo apontado nas duas instâncias.

Idealmente você deveria alocar sua própria área para armazenamento do nome e copiar o conteúdo com `strlen`:

```
asset->name = new char[asset->name_sz];
strncpy(asset->name, filename, asset->name_sz);
```

---

Note também que na deleção das suas estruturas você também precisa liberar a memória utilizada pelos elementos internos. Por exemplo, no seu código atual tem um potencial vazamento de memória (*memory leak*) no tratamento da falha do `fread`:

```
. . .
if(fread(&asset->data[0], sizeof(char), asset->data_sz, file) == 0) {
    delete asset;
    asset = NULL;

    fclose(file);
}
. . .
```

No caso de falha você executa diretamente o `delete` na variável `asset` mas não deleta a memória alocada para `asset->data`. Como você está usando C++ (ao menos está na tag da pergunta), eu sugiro que você use classes ao invés de estruturas pois assim pode procurar garantir que as devidas liberações de memória sejam feitas no destrutor.

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo. Então como posso passar uma `string` para uma função sem causar este problema?. Tirando o método que você disse.

Comment: Como está usando C++, uma ideia seria usar std::string em tudo, que essa classe faz as cópias para você, e é mais seguro do que fazer manualmente new + strncpy (que é um estilo “muito C” e que só se deve usar em C++ caso seja necessário implementar algo de alta performance em baixo nível).

Comment: Isso mesmo, o @marcus deu a dica: use `string` diretamente. :)

Answer (score 2):

Olhando rápido o seu código, percebi isso:

```
std::string name;

name = "1.txt";
asset_mgr->addFile(name.c_str());

name = "2.txt";
asset_mgr->addFile(name.c_str());
```

Você possui apenas 1 string chamada name, que recebe "1.txt" e depois é sobrescrita com "2.txt". Ao passar para addFile, você está usando o método c_str(), que pega apenas o ponteiro para o começo da string.

Mas se guardar só o ponteiro, acontece isso, a modificação num lugar afeta outro (ou pior, se a string for realocada, o ponteiro antigo fica inválido e pode causar um crash ou exibir dados inválidos).

Se você usar apenas std::string, a cada atribuição ou passagem de parâmetro será feita uma cópia (que pode ser evitada com referência const: `const std::string &`). Se você quiser mesmo usar ponteiros, você terá que decidir com bastante cuidado onde fazer cópias, e onde manter ponteiros (cuidando para que eles continuem válidos por todo o tempo que forem necessários)